# How insert,update,delete for a record go to same container among multiple in kuberenetes?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

My question is How Insert,Update,Delete query will go to same container when multiple container of mongod running in Kubernetes Cluster ?
Any Help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

Deploying Statefull apps in K8s is really challenging when you have multiple replicas. Because as you said, all the replicas should aware of `CRUD` operations

For this, you have to deploy MongoDB as cluster and define `StatefulSets`. Below are the links starting point to explore more.

- https://kubedb.com/docs/0.9.0/guides/mongodb/clustering/replicaset/
- http://k8smongodb.net/
- https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/